# Python correlation (.corr) results as dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, correlation

I am running the following code with a dataset named "mpg_data"

```
mpg_data.corr(method='pearson').style.format("{:.2}")
```

As a result I get the data I need as a table. However, when I try to assign these results to a variable, so I can get them as a usable dataframe, doing this:

```
results = mpg_data.corr(method='pearson').style.format("{:.2}")
```

As a result I get:

```
<pandas.formats.style.Styler object at 0x130379e90>
```

How can I get the correlation result as a usable dataframe?

Comment: `results = mpg_data.corr(method='pearson')`

Answer (score 1):

Drop the `.style...`

`results = mpg_data.corr(arguments)`

This should return the correlation matrix as a dataframe. If you want to display just two digits, you can actually do this in matplotlib or use `.apply()` on the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You might use the dataframe applymap instead of style.feature:

```
results = mpg_data.corr(method='pearson').applymap('${:,.2f}'.format)
```